# Rendering a <textarea /> using data annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, textarea, data-annotations, multiline

I'd like to render a text area for one of the fields in my model.

I've tried applying `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]` to my field, but this doesn't do the trick.

At the moment, I am rendering the text area manually but I'd much prefer to use `Html.EditorFor`. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should post the code for the property that has the data annotation, and the code for the view where you are using `Html.EditorFor`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use:

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.YourProperty)
```

EditorFor helper is sort of "smart" helper and it's basing the rendering based on the underlying type of the property. If you want to enforce it to render a specific html input type then use other helpers.

Comment: Oh yeah, never thought of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 53):

`[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]` only works if you use `Html.EditorFor` helper in your view:

Sample:

**Model**

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
Html.EditorFor(m => m.Description)
```

Comment: This works great when you're being lazy, my favorite!

Comment: I think this is a better, more reusable answer.